# org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit, batch-processing

I am writing unit test case using JUnit in STS.The classes are

TestConfiguration.java

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan("com.kgfsl.collections.core")
 public class TestConfiguration {

@Bean
@Inject
public org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new  
LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.kgfsl.collections.core.models");
    sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}

private static Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    final org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
    configuration.setProperty(HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");
    configuration.setProperty(DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

    // Test Default settings
    configuration.setProperty(CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
    configuration.setProperty(USE_GET_GENERATED_KEYS, "true");
    configuration.setProperty(USE_REFLECTION_OPTIMIZER, "true");
    configuration.setProperty(ORDER_UPDATES, "true");
    configuration.setProperty(ORDER_INSERTS, "true");
    configuration.setProperty(USE_NEW_ID_GENERATOR_MAPPINGS, "true");
    return configuration.getProperties();
 }


}
```

BaseRepositoryTest.java

```
@RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {UserManagementTestConfiguration.class})
public abstract class BaseRepositoryTest extends
    AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

@Inject
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Transaction transaction;

public Session getSession() {
    Session session;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } catch (SessionException se) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    return session;
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    transaction = getSession().beginTransaction();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    if (transaction != null) {
        transaction.rollback();
    }
    getSession().close();
}

@Before
public void baseSetUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }
}
```

UserRoleDaoTest.java

```
  public class UserRoleDaoTest extends BaseRepositoryTest
 {  
  @Autowired
  private UserRoleDao userroleDao;

 @Test
 public void shouldCreateRole()
 {
    UserRole userRole=new UserRoleBuilder().userroleBuilder(10,"Md Aslam", 
     "N","1").build();

    UserRole userroleCreated=userroleDao.persist(userRole);
    UserRole userroleGet = userroleDao.findById(userroleCreated.getRoleId());
    Assert.assertThat(userroleGet.getRoleName(), Is.is("Md Aslam"));
    Assert.assertThat(userroleGet.getRoleId(), Is.is(10));

    UserRole userroleCreate=userroleDao.persist(userRole);
    Assert.assertNotNull(userRole.getRoleId());
 }

 @Test
 public void shouldGetRoleById()
 {
    UserRole userRole=new UserRoleBuilder().userroleBuilder(10,"Md Aslam",
     "N","1").build();
    UserRole userroleCreated=userroleDao.persist(userRole);
    UserRole userroleGet = userroleDao.findById(userroleCreated.getRoleId());
    assertNotNull(userroleGet);
    Assert.assertThat(userroleGet.getRoleId(), Is.is(10));
    }

 @Test
 public void shouldUpdateAccount()
 {
    UserRole userRole=new UserRoleBuilder().userroleBuilder(10,"aslam",
     "N","1").build();
    UserRole userroleCreated=userroleDao.persist(userRole);

    UserRole userroleGet = userroleDao.findById(userroleCreated.getRoleId());
    Assert.assertEquals(userRole.getRoleId(), userroleGet.getRoleId());
    UserRole userRoleForUpdate=new   
    UserRoleBuilder().userroleBuilder(userroleCreated.getRoleId(),"Md Aslam", 
     "Y","1").build();
    userroleDao.update(userRoleForUpdate);
 } 

@Test
public void shouldGetRoleByName()
{

        UserRole userRole=new UserRoleBuilder().userroleBuilder(10,"aslam",  
          "N","1").build();
        UserRole userroleCreated=userroleDao.persist(userRole);

    UserRole userrolegetbyname=userroleDao.findByRoleName(userRole.getRoleName());
    assertNotNull(userrolegetbyname);

    }

 }
```

When I run this class, it shows error like

```
    shouldGetRoleByName:org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned  
    unexpected row count from  Update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

The actual method for shouldGetRoleByName is that

```
   public UserRole findByRoleName(String roleName) {
     UserRole userPermission = (UserRole) 
           criteria().setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                .add(eq("roleName", roleName.trim().toLowerCase())).uniqueResult();
        return userPermission;
    }
```

All methods in the test case are passed except shouldGetRoleByName () this method.And 
I tried in many ways but I can't get a solution for it, if anybody knows the solution for it please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Hibernate is keeping all changes in memory and executing a flush (send the changes to database) only when a query is triggered in the "shouldGetRoleByName" method.
At this time the update called in the "shouldUpdateAccount" is sent to the database and it fails (affects zero records).

Try to invoke "flush" at the end of the "shouldUpdateAccount" method and check if the error moves to there. If so, you can investigate your code to better understand its  behaviour. Note that all entities modifications performed in a session are sent to the database only at specific times (ex: when you commit a transacion or when you execute a query).

Comment: Actually, that is not a problem. Because I tried without shouldUpdateAccount () method.

Answer (score 0):

100% working solution!!!! just write save instead of saveOrUpdate in your hibernate query... because due to previous logs your class is generating some other id which was previously stored in ur table ,so hibernate tries to update with same id and it finds no row with that id so it gives staleStateException.